# problems with populating datagridview with data from binary file

Tags: c#, datagridview, binaryfiles

I have this code that will read data from a binary file, and then print it in a datagridview. The final result is, it creates the columns as I want and creates the number of rows equal to the data that comes from the binary file but it doesn't show me the data. Fill in blank, how can I solve it?

```cs
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog localizarArquivoDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        localizarArquivoDialog.Filter = "Arquivos Binários (*.bin)|*.bin";
        localizarArquivoDialog.DefaultExt = "bin";

        DialogResult resultado = localizarArquivoDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            caminhoArquivo = localizarArquivoDialog.FileName;

            // Limpar o ArrayList antes de carregar os novos dados
            clientes.Clear();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(caminhoArquivo, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    while (reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length)
                    {
                        string codigoCliente = reader.ReadString();
                        string nome = reader.ReadString();
                        string nif = reader.ReadString();
                        string email = reader.ReadString();
                        MessageBox.Show("Dados carregados com sucesso!" + nome);
                        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(codigoCliente, nome, nif, email);
                        clientes.Add(cliente);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Configurar as colunas do DataGridView
            dataGridViewClientes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Clear();

            // Configurar cada coluna manualmente
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add("codigoCliente", "codigoCliente");
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns["codigoCliente"].DataPropertyName = "codigoCliente";

            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add("nome", "nome");
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns["nome"].DataPropertyName = "nome";

            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add("nif", "nif");
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns["nif"].DataPropertyName = "nif";

            dataGridViewClientes.Columns.Add("email", "email");
            dataGridViewClientes.Columns["email"].DataPropertyName = "email";
            
            dataGridViewClientes.DataSource = clientes;
            //MessageBox.Show("Dados carregados com sucesso!");
        }
        else
        {
            caminhoArquivo = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Nenhum arquivo selecionado.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have here `Cliente` model already, so instead of doing this, use a reliable serializer (json, xml) to serialize a `List<Cliente>`. Then, you just `.Save` and `.Load` your data and bind the grid. Find in SO Q&As about serialization.